# How do I add the postgres plugin to Google Cloud Data Fusion?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'd like to write to a postgres database. Cloud Data Fusion's database sink contains an example on how to do this. I followed the example, but when attempting to deploy the pipeline surfaces an error saying I need to install the jdbc plugin for postgres. I installed the PostgresSQL and the JDBC (first 8, then 7) drivers within the hub menu. Any thing else to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric can you make sure that the driver name that you provide when you upload the driver matches the configuration provided in the sink. By default the name that is used is postgresql if you follow the defaults in Hub.

Comment: HI Sree, I toggled betweed the three Postgres plugins until I found the right combination (not sure which but it started working).